# How to query for One - Many Relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two database tables with "one to many" relationship

let say, table A and Table B

One field from Table A is a foreign key in table B
I wanna fetch just one record from table A as well as table B (given table A's primary key)

table A

```
id                name
--------------------
1                 ABC
2                 XYZ
```

Table B

```
id              A_id                      email
------------------------------------------------
1                 1                 temp@temp1.com
2                 1                 temp@temp2.com
3                 1                 temp@temp3.com
4                 2                 temp@temp4.com
4                 2                 temp@temp5.com
```

Answer should be like this (Single Record From Table B)

For a.id = 1

```
A.id, A.name,B.email
-------------------------
1, ABC, temp@temp1.com
```

For a.id = 2

```
A.id, A.name,B.email
-------------------------
1, XYZ, temp@temp4.com
```

I used this query, but it returns all the records from table B(as table B has multiple records for each record in Table A)

```
SELECT a.id,a.name, b.email FROM A a, B b WHERE a.id = 1 AND b.A_id = a.id
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL PHPMyAdmin

Comment: MySQL is an RDBMS, PHPMyAdmin is a tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a SQL Fiddle for the demo here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15ae7/5

The query that you can use for getting the desired output is:

```
SELECT 
tableA.id,
tableA.name,
tableB.email 
FROM tableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB ON tableB.A_id = tableA.id
GROUP BY tableB.A_id;
```

For more information on JOINS and GROUP BY you can refer to the following pages:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

Try a `JOIN`

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.name,
    b.email 
FROM A a
LEFT JOIN B b ON b.A_id = a.id
WHERE a.id = 1;
GROUP BY b.A_id
```

[More info on JOINS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIMIT if you want only one record.

```
SELECT a.id,a.name, b.email FROM A a, B b WHERE a.id = 1 AND b.A_id = a.id LIMIT 0,1
```

Hope this helps you.